# How do I make `XmlSerializer` to ignore `IXmlSerializer` implementation?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, ixmlserializable

Based on a certain flag, I need to switch between the default XmlSerialization deserializer and IXmlSerialization interface implementation. How can I do that?
E.g.

```
  public class SomeClass: IXmlSerializer
  { 
     //Other primitive and complex properties
     //...
     // 
    
     //Another issue is - What would be the best way to inject depencencies? 
     SomeClass(ISomeDepedency dependency)
     {
     }

     public ReadXml(XmlReader rdr)
     {
       var someValues =   dependency.GetSomeValuesFromDBForCustomSerializtion();               
     }
  }

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   
   //This is filled out
   XmlReader rdr = null;

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeClass));
    if(useCustomSerializer)
    { 
       //use IXmlSerializer implemenation
    }
   else
   {
          //use Default Serializer
   }
   var someClass= serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
  }
```

I know that IXmlSerializer implementation is all or nothing.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You need three methods 1)ReadXml, WriteXml, and GetSchema.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=net-6.0,  The read method you can create a child serizilzer : XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ChildClass));.  Then deserialize the child with the same reader or create a new child reader.

Comment: See my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72843947/deserialize-xml-with-different-type-rows-c-sharp/72845615#72845615

Comment: I removed the other 2 for brevity. "the read method you can create....." , I have many types within the class, which would mean many switch cases. In the event someone adds a new type within the class, that needs to be part of that switch as well.

Comment: Does the produced XML need to fit any specific schema/format or any deserializable XML will do it? If the latter, you can try [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#xml-serialization) serializer (disclaimer: written by me). It respects `IXmlSerializable` implementation by default but it has an `IgnoreIXmlSerializable` serialization option.

Comment: The switch was only needed to split the row tags into two lists.  I usually use Xml Linq using XElement.ReadFrom(reader).

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this.  Easiest workaround may be to create a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and use that instead.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg, it's the former. Thanks for your input.